# Remove from set of matched Elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

I have the following example html:

```
<div id="root">
    <span>A</span><!--select-->
    <span>B</span><!--select-->
    <div>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>D</span>
        <div>
            <span>E</span>
        </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        <span>F</span><!--select-->
        <div>
            <span>G</span>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to select all `spans` except the ones, that are childs of other `divs`. `spans` that are children of other elements (such as `p, button` **or anything else**) shoud be selected. The `p` is just an example. This means I want to have `span A, B and F`. I tried:

```
$("#root").find("span").not("div span");
```

But `.not("div span")` removes all spans as the root Element is also a `div`. Is there a way with jQuery?

Comment: Your html is invalid as `p` can't have `div` as its child

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You're correct. It's a poor example, but it shows what I want to do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```js
$('#root span').not('#root div span').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <span>A</span>
  <!--select-->
  <span>B</span>
  <!--select-->
  <div>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <div>
      <span>E</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <span>F</span>
    <!--select-->
    <div>
      <span>G</span>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Note: Your html is invalid as `p` can't have `div` element as its child.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a selector to target immediate child span elements and span elements in immediate p element:

```
var target = $("#root").find("> span, >*:not(div) span");
```

```js
 $(function(){
    $("#root").find("> span,*:not(div) span").css('color','red');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
    <span>A</span><!--select-->
    <span>B</span><!--select-->
    <div>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>D</span>
        <div>
            <span>E</span>
        </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        <span>F</span><!--select-->
        <div>
            <span>G</span>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't tell if there's a `p` or something else. The only thing that is sure is that I don't want the spans that are children of other divs except the root element. Every other span should be selected. `p` was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` method:

```js
$('#root span').filter(function(){
    return this.parentNode.id == 'root' || this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'div'
}).addClass('found');
```

```css
.found{border:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <span>A</span>
  <!--select-->
  <span>B</span>
  <!--select-->
  <div>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <div>
      <span>E</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        <span>F</span>
        <!--select-->
        <div>
          <span>G</span>
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

$("#root").find("span").not("#root>span");